# How to find a string in a file and take next word as input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I do have a config file which has a structure like this:

```
username abc123
licensekey qwer1234
```

The file is located in `$HOME/.test.config`.

Now I want to search for the keyword `licensekey` and want to copy the following word `qwer1234` as my key. If the word license key is not present or the file doesn't exist I want the user to add a license key manually and crate the file.

Do you have any suggestions? And did I made some mistakes in my code so far?

My code so far is:

```
keyfile='$HOME/.test.config'
if grep -q licensekey "$keyfile"; then
    #what now?
else
    while true; do
        read -p "Whats your License Key? " key
        key >> ${keyfile}
        break
    done
fi
```

Comment: Couple of points: `'$HOME'` won't expand, you have to use double quotes: `"$HOME"`; `key >> ${keyfile}` will try to run a (non-existing) command `key`, you probably meant something like `echo "$key" >> "$keyfile"`. You also don't seem to need the while loop as you break out of it after the first iteration anyway.

Comment: I had "\$HOME". I want it to be $HOME. it is a variable in the system. not in the script. I think "$HOME" woul search for the variable HOME in my script.

ye. it has to be echo -e "${key}". I forgot it. It was just fast writing here while adding it.

I think I need the while loop. If there is not licensekey I want the user to write one by himself. Somewhere I read that I need a while loop for it or else the input won't be correct.

Comment: `$HOME` expands to the current user's home directory, typically `/home/$USER`, where `$USER` is the username. If you write `'$HOME'` or `"\$HOME"`, it expands to literally `$HOME`, and that directory most likely doesn't exist and isn't what you meant. Quoting prevents the shell from word splitting and globbing, but in this case, because `$HOME` is on the right-hand-side of an assignment, you can actually leave it safely unquoted: `keyfile=$HOME/.test.config` should work fine.

Comment: And `while true; do command; break; done` is the same as `command`.

Comment: The `while` loop is not necessary as you are not validating the user input. Also in the code above the `while` will not help much because we are `break`ing after the first read

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to match the string in the file and extract the key

**Example**

```
$ cat file
username abc123
licensekey qwer1234

$ awk '$1 == "licensekey"{print $2}' file
qwer1234
```

---

To read the `key` from the user if not in file, we can write something like

```
key=$(awk '$1 == "licensekey"{print $2}' file)
if [[ -z $key ]]
then
        read -p "Whats your License Key? " key
        echo "licensekey $key" >> file
fi
# Do something with the kye
```

Comment: It looks like OP also wants to let the user enter the license key manually if not present.

Comment: @jraynal I agree, my post answers  *How to find a string in a file and take next word as input?* part of the question only. But the reading part is not completely clear from op's questions.

Comment: Ye. I want to user to add a license key if there is none. I forgot it.

Comment: @ChrizZly I have added an update to read the key and write it to the file.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what exactly -z does? And why do I need 2 brackets?

Comment: `[[` are for testing stuff. `-z` checks wether `$key` is of zero length

Comment: How can I suppress the output of awk? 
I always get the error message: There is no file /home/username/test.config. (the file shouldnt exist by opening the script first time)

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` and `cut`:

```
grep licensekey config_file | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sed` to parse out the licensekey:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
set -o nounset # error if variable not set
set -o errexit # exit if error

# Using double quote let bash expand the variable
# Local limit the scope of the variable
local keyfile="${HOME}/.test.config"

#gets the first valid key
local key=$(sed -n 's/licensekey[[:space:]]//p')

#Append the key to file if not existing
if [ -z "${key}" ]; then
    read -r -p "Whats your License Key? " key
    echo "licensekey ${key}" >> ${keyfile}
fi

echo "License key is: ${key}"
```